# Parsing and saving Google Vision API response as JSON

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am currently testing out the Google Vision API for some basic handwritten text recognition and have no troubles getting a decent response for my image.

However, I am struggling to save the received response locally. I have tried several ways of parsing the AnnotateImageResponse. I tried:

- using MessageToJson and MessageToDict from google.protobuf.json_format
- response.SerializeToString() inside json.loads()
- saving the response as a binary file and reloading it from the disk for JSON parsing
- saving only parts of the response (response.text_annotations and response.full_text_annotation individually)

I keep getting an error telling me that the object does not have an attribute called 'DESCRIPTOR'.

When I looked into the response.txt file I created from turning the response into a String, I realized that the full_text_annotations do not have said descriptor tag on the top level keys, so I thought saving only the text_annotations would solve this. Unfortunately not, I am still getting the same error.

This is my code so far (not working)

```
import io
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from google.cloud import vision
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
from google.protobuf import json_format

vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
path = './images/'
name = 'test.jpg'
with io.open(path+name, 'rb') as image_file:
    opened_image = image_file.read()
image = vision.Image(content=opened_image)
response = vision_client.document_text_detection(image=image, image_context={"language_hints": ["en-t-i0-handwrit"]})

# tried extracting only whole words here - doesn't work
all_words = response.text_annotations
all_words_json = MessageToJson(all_words)

# Causes AttributeError: 'RepeatedComposite' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

All help is appreciated, either with regards to how to turn the response into a JSON file directly or how to correctly iterate over it to turn it into a JSON that way. Thanks!

This is a part of the received Cloud Vision response:

```
...

text_annotations {
  description: "Congratulations"
  bounding_poly {
    vertices {
      x: 2334
      y: 2452
    }
    vertices {
      x: 3284
      y: 2464
    }
    vertices {
      x: 3282
      y: 2615
    }
    vertices {
      x: 2332
      y: 2603
    }
  }
}
text_annotations {
  description: "!"
  bounding_poly {
    vertices {
      x: 3321
      y: 2464
    }
    vertices {
      x: 3411
      y: 2465
    }
    vertices {
      x: 3409
      y: 2615
    }
    vertices {
      x: 3319
      y: 2614
    }
  }
}
full_text_annotation {
  pages {
    property {
      detected_languages {
        language_code: "en"
        confidence: 0.991942465
      }
    }
    width: 4032
    height: 3024
    blocks {
      bounding_box {
        vertices {
          x: 446
          y: 486
        }
        vertices {
          x: 3541
          y: 475
        }
        vertices {
          x: 3549
          y: 2618
        }
        vertices {
          x: 454
          y: 2629
        }
      }
      paragraphs {
        bounding_box {
          vertices {
            x: 2490
            y: 912
          }
          vertices {
            x: 2633
            y: 910
          }
          vertices {
            x: 2634
            y: 957
          }
          vertices {
            x: 2491
            y: 959
          }
        }
        words {
          bounding_box {
            vertices {
              x: 2490
              y: 912
            }
            vertices {
              x: 2633
              y: 910
            }
            vertices {
              x: 2634
              y: 957
            }
            vertices {
              x: 2491
              y: 959
            }
          }
          symbols {
            bounding_box {
              vertices {
                x: 2490
                y: 913
              }
              vertices {
                x: 2552
                y: 912
              }
              vertices {
                x: 2553
                y: 958
              }
              vertices {
                x: 2491
                y: 959
              }
            }
            text: "a"
            confidence: 0.961887
          }
          symbols {
            property {
              detected_break {
                type_: LINE_BREAK
              }
            }
            bounding_box {
              vertices {
                x: 2552
                y: 911
              }
              vertices {
                x: 2633
                y: 910
              }
              vertices {
                x: 2634
                y: 955
              }
              vertices {
                x: 2553
                y: 956
              }
            }
            text: "m"
            confidence: 0.957640529
          }
          confidence: 0.959763765
        }
        confidence: 0.959763765
      }
      paragraphs {
        bounding_box {
          vertices {
            x: 471
            y: 485
          }

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out now: the AnnotateImageResponse is a ProtoBuffer object, so a special notation needs to be used when passing the response to the MessageToJson function:

```
# response is a ProtoBuffer object, so use ._pb notation
json_response = MessageToJson(response._pb)

# save response_json as a .json file
with open('response.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_response)
```

Note that we pass `response._pb` instead of `response` to `MessageToJson()`.

Comment: Why don't they have that in the docs? Only Lord knows.

Answer (score 0):

While the given answer is perfectly fine, I found that the class `AnnotateImageResponse` has methods to serialize/deserialize to/from json as of now.

```
# serialize to json string from an object of type AnnotateImageResponse 
json_response = AnnotateImageResponse.to_json(response)

# deserialize from json to an object of type AnnotateImageResponse
response = AnnotateImageResponse.from_json(json_response)
```